# Must certain rings be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{a}]$ for some $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Consider the group $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},+)$, where $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$. Let $\times$ be any binary operation on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ is a ring. Must there exist a non-square integer "$a$" such that
$$(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},+,\times)\cong\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{a}]?$$

Thank you.

**Edit:** Chris Eagle noted that setting $x\times y=0$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ would provide a counterexample. I would like to see other ecounterexamples though.

Comment: Do you require your rings to have a unit?

Comment: @MihaHabic No. not necessarily.

Comment: Then the answer is obviously no: you could declare every product to be $0$, for exampele.

Comment: @ChrisEagle  You are right. I would also be glad to see another counterexample.

Comment: How would you express $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with componentwise multiplication as a ring of your form?

Comment: How about the quotient ring of ${\bf Z}[x]$ by the ideal generated by some reducible quadratic like $x^2-4$ or $x^2$ or $(x-1)(x-2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most natural counterexample is the following:

If the operation $\times$ is defined such that the resulting ring is simply product of two copies of the usual ring $(\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ (that is, if we set $(a,b)\times(c,d)=(ac,bd)$), then, again, no isomorphism exists, since the resulting ring $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{a}]$ is.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, the [zero ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring) on the group $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ is not of this form.

Comment: +1 Thank you. It would be great if there are other examples.